# Automatically detect Xpath from user given item as input

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am writing a Flask application which runs the Scrapy spider to crawl the given website. Flask application provides a UI which takes the URL to be scrapped and an ITEM to be scrapped ( say job title for [website](http://jobs.placementindia.com/lucknow) ).

Now, the problem is that, how the spider detects the Xpath automatically of the user given ITEM ????

Following is the code for spider ( with hard-coded Xpath):

```
class StackItem(scrapy.Item):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key not in self.fields:
            self.fields[key] = scrapy.Field()
        self._values[key] = value


class newAppSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "appSpider"


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super(newAppSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        self.start_urls = [kwargs.get('start_url')]

    rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('.*\?id1=.*',),restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="prevNext next"]',))
, callback="parse_items", follow= True),)


    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        posts = hxs.select("//article[@class='classified']")
        items = []

        for post in posts:
            item = StackItem()
            item[self.settings['MY_PROPERTY']] = post.select("div[@class='uu mb2px']/a/strong/text()").extract() 
            items.append(item)

            for item in items:
                yield item
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more with an example what you want to extract with the XPath when the user defines an item-property?

Comment: Lets suppose, user enters the URL  as  ' http://jobs.placementindia.com/lucknow ' and  " Job Title " as Item on Flask web page. How the above spider detects the xpath of HTML tag which contains the "Job Title" on above website ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you go for a text in a node-set (each job posting) you have to iterate over the nodes of your posting and see if the node contains the text you need.

This is a big problem with XPath if you want to get it very generic.

But filtering if a specific post contains this text you could use something like this:

```
for post in posts:
    text_node = self.find_text(post, "Job Title")
        if text_node:
            print text_node.xpath('text()').extract()
```

And the `find_text` function which goes into the spider (this could be improved a bit more):

```
def find_text(self, node, text):
    for child in node.xpath("./child::node()"):
        if child.xpath("./text()[contains(.,'{0}')]".format(text)).extract():
            return child
        if child.xpath(".//text()[contains(.,'{0}')]".format(text)).extract():
            return self.find_text(child, text)
```

**Note** that `contains` of XPath is case sensitive. This means *Job Title* does not equal with *job title*.

However if you look at the site, then you will see that "Job Title" would give a minor problem because that tag contains a bit more than just only the job title.

**One more thing**

Because you use a Rule your `start_url` is not parsed. This is obvious if you enter "Job Title" as the search text and it will find somewhere deeper a job description with this text in it. To solve this issue you have to override the `parse_start_url` function of the spider:

```
def parse_start_url(self, response):
    self.parse_items(response)
```

**For the start-up error**

Put quotes around the value you get from your Flask site:

```
command = "scrapy crawl appSpider -a start_url=" + request.form['url'] + '-s MY_PROPERTY="' + request.form['tag1']+'"'
```

Comment: Thanks for such a clean solution. But, I am not getting anything after adding it to spider code, when i am searching for job_title.

Comment: This is because "job_title" is not in the text of the website. Neither is it as a tag or `class` of a tag defined. If it is not there then you will obviously find nothing. An alternative would be to let enter the user the text (for example "Job Title") and not "job_title".

Comment: When i am entering "Job Title", it throws an error :

' crawl: error: running 'scrapy crawl' with more than one spider is no longer supported '

Comment: Example updated, it was my fault. However with the error message in your comment: how do you run the spider?

Comment: i have updated my question with the code which is responsible for running spider.

Comment: After adding your updated code, m not getting any results. Please, review it again..!! :)

Comment: On my machine I am getting results so I cannot help more. Even the script starts when I surround the parameter with quotes -- however I am not using Flask but this has nothing to do with it.

Comment: ok. have you skipped following section of code or not ? :


     ' def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super(newAppSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        #self.start_urls = [kwargs.get('start_url')]

    rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(unique=True, allow=('.*\?id1=.*',),restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="prevNext next"]',))
    , callback="parse_items", follow= True),) '

Comment: And one more thing, please share your complete running code.So that, i can figure out where i am making mistake.!!!
Thank you..!! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87448/discussion-between-ghajba-and-ooorza).